# javafx timeline and mouse event

Tags: java, javafx

when I run this code this, the action will stop when the mouse click.
The ball will stop action when I click mouse. how do I make the ball do the action continuously although I click the mouse to add other balls.

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class GamePractice extends Application {

    public static Circle circle;
    public static Pane canvas;

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {

        canvas = new Pane();
        final Scene scene = new Scene(canvas, 800, 600);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Game");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        circle = new Circle(15, Color.BLUE);
        circle.relocate(100, 100);

        canvas.getChildren().addAll(circle);


        final Timeline loop = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(10), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            double deltaX = (double)(Math.random()*10) + 3;
            double deltaY = (double)(Math.random()*10) + 3;
            @Override
            public void handle(final ActionEvent t) {
                circle.setLayoutX(circle.getLayoutX() + deltaX);
                circle.setLayoutY(circle.getLayoutY() + deltaY);

                final Bounds bounds = canvas.getBoundsInLocal();
                final boolean atRightBorder = circle.getLayoutX() >= (bounds.getMaxX() - circle.getRadius());
                final boolean atLeftBorder = circle.getLayoutX() <= (bounds.getMinX() + circle.getRadius());
                final boolean atBottomBorder = circle.getLayoutY() >= (bounds.getMaxY() - circle.getRadius());
                final boolean atTopBorder = circle.getLayoutY() <= (bounds.getMinY() + circle.getRadius());

                if (atRightBorder || atLeftBorder) {
                    deltaX *= -1;
                }
                if (atBottomBorder || atTopBorder) {
                    deltaY *= -1;
                }

            }
        }));

        scene.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {         
            @Override         
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {  
                if (event.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
                    if (!(canvas.getChildren().isEmpty())) {
                        canvas.getChildren().remove(0);
                    }   
                }
                else {
                    int red = (int)(Math.random()*256);
                    int green = (int)(Math.random()*256);
                    int blue = (int)(Math.random()*256);
                    int x = (int)(Math.random()*801);
                    int y = (int)(Math.random()*601);
                    circle = new Circle(15, Color.rgb(red, green, blue));
                    circle.relocate(x, y);
                    canvas.getChildren().addAll(circle);
                }
            }     
        }); 

        loop.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        loop.play();
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post code that will compile? It is really not clear what this is supposed to do. (You are resetting the event handler on the scene one hundred times per second?)

Comment: I have edited it. Now, the previous ball will stop their motion when I click right to add new ball. I want all ball move.

Comment: Sure, because the animation only updates one circle, and you replace the circle that's referenced by it. You need to keep a `List<Circle>`. As an aside, why did you make the fields static?

Comment: Thank you. I'm new in java. how do I change it to list.

Comment: Actually, instead of that approach, just create a new timeline for each circle you add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create an animation for each circle:

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class GamePractice extends Application {

    private Pane canvas;

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {

        canvas = new Pane();
        final Scene scene = new Scene(canvas, 800, 600);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Game");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        addCircle(100, 100, Color.BLUE);


        scene.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {         
            @Override         
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {  
                if (event.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
                    if (!(canvas.getChildren().isEmpty())) {
                        canvas.getChildren().remove(0);
                    }   
                }
                else {
                    int red = (int)(Math.random()*256);
                    int green = (int)(Math.random()*256);
                    int blue = (int)(Math.random()*256);
                    int x = (int)(Math.random()*801);
                    int y = (int)(Math.random()*601);
                    addCircle(x, y, Color.rgb(red, green, blue));
                }
            }     
        }); 

    }

    private void addCircle(double x, double y, Color color) {
        Circle circle = new Circle(15, color);
        circle.relocate(x, y);

        canvas.getChildren().addAll(circle);


        final Timeline loop = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(10), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            double deltaX = (double)(Math.random()*10) + 3;
            double deltaY = (double)(Math.random()*10) + 3;


            @Override
            public void handle(final ActionEvent t) {
                circle.setLayoutX(circle.getLayoutX() + deltaX);
                circle.setLayoutY(circle.getLayoutY() + deltaY);

                final Bounds bounds = canvas.getBoundsInLocal();
                final boolean atRightBorder = circle.getLayoutX() >= (bounds.getMaxX() - circle.getRadius());
                final boolean atLeftBorder = circle.getLayoutX() <= (bounds.getMinX() + circle.getRadius());
                final boolean atBottomBorder = circle.getLayoutY() >= (bounds.getMaxY() - circle.getRadius());
                final boolean atTopBorder = circle.getLayoutY() <= (bounds.getMinY() + circle.getRadius());

                if (atRightBorder || atLeftBorder) {
                    deltaX *= -1;
                }
                if (atBottomBorder || atTopBorder) {
                    deltaY *= -1;
                }
            }
        }));

        loop.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        loop.play();

    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```